# Journey Builder - Decision Split Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We've got an email studio audience that we want to do a decision split on after sending an email (with a 7 day wait between). We're making the decision based on the entry DE, but whatever filter we create we get an Invalid Expression error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the error disappears if you save your journey.

Comment: I don't think saving the journey remove the error, it just ignore it. Can you activate the journey?

Answer (score 0):

I get this every time I edit the attribute group in data designer i.e unlink the DE referenced in the decision split. Have you checked there yet?